# Speed up loading of new tab page for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im making a chrome extension for new tab page.. The page itself loads fast but there's a bit of a lag for chrome itself to redirect to my page.. What I do notice is that if you already have a new tab page open and you open another new tab ontop of it that it's really quick.. Any ideas how to speed it up? I'm wondering if preloading it in the background page may help? Any ideas are welcomed..

For the new tab page functionality, I am using this in the manifest:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
   "newtab": "mtp4.html"
 },
```

Comment: Some code / page structure would help make this answerable.

Comment: I don't see how it's relevant, any tab page that opens takes a few seconds to actually load.. as soon as Chrome actually redirects it to the right page then it takes less than half a second..

Comment: What are you using as a new tab page, and how do you tell Chrome to use it? Because there are several possible ways I can think of.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Do you load any external resources in that HTML page? Does JS in that page load any? If yes, you may want to wrap all that loading in document ready event to indicate to Chrome that the page is safe to display (or rather, start displaying) in case it decided to prerender first.

Comment: All resources loaded are locally - do you think it would be better to load it on document ready instead?

Comment: It does not hurt to try to move as much as possible to document ready and see if it affects the loading time.

Comment: Just having an empty background page helps a lot.

Comment: @Xan I tried it and it doesn't seem to make any difference.. 

wOxxOm could you elaborate?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but does your page start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`? I've seen much weirdness if a quirks-mode page is loaded in Chrome UI.

Comment: My page starts with <html>.. should I be putting doctype instead?

Comment: You should put that line above `<html>`.